# Brushless motor esc and voltage

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

If brushless motor work in 22.2 volt , if I provide the ESC with 24 volt 
Is there a problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Probably not -- with anything involving a motor, you usually have leeway to stretch the specifications.  The motor may turn a bit fast, and will draw a bit more current when it's stalled, but you're talking about a 10% difference there, so you'll probably be OK.  Monitor the current if you're worried, and lighten the load if it's pulling too much.

Moreover, if the ESC is specified for 22.2V then it's for six Lithium-Polymer cells, which (briefly) produce 25.2V (4.2V per cell) when they're fully charged.

Even if you're thinking of using a "24V" lead acid battery (which is something like 27.6V as it's being charged) you should still be OK.